# Implicit conversion is applied when supposedly equivalent implicit class is not

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have this fairly simple example where one function `foo()`, which takes an implicit argument of type `A`, tries to call another function `bar()`, which takes an implicit argument of type `B`. In the project where I ran into this question, `B` contains a subset of the functionality of `A`, so I would like to provide an *implicit conversion* from `A` to `B` to make cases like in this example seamless.

Implementing this using the implicit conversion `B.implicitConversion()` works as expected. The following code is accepted by `scalac` 2.13.0:

```
trait A

trait B

object B {
  // implicit class ImplicitClass(value: A) extends B

  implicit def implicitConversion(implicit se: A) = ???
}

class Test {
  def foo()(implicit a: A) = bar()

  def bar()(implicit b: B) = ???
}
```

Oddly enough, implementing the conversion using the *implicit class* `ImplicitClass` does not work (by removing the definition of `implicitConversion()` and adding the definition of `ImplicitClass`). The code is rejected by `scalac`:

```
$ scalac 'Test.scala:12: error: could not find implicit value for parameter b: B
def foo()(implicit a: A) = bar()
^
one error found
```

I would have assumed that in such a situation implicit classes and implicit conversion are interchangeable. What am I missing here, why are the two ways of providing a conversion not equivalent?

Comment: Implicit classes are only used for **extension methods** not for **implicit conversions**, since in the place where it has to find the _implicits_ you are not directly calling any method of the `B` class, then it is not used. Wheres, the implicit conversion will be applied. - Note that, implicit conversions are discouraged for very good reasons. It would be better if you do this instead `trait A extends B`. This way, if you have an instance of `A` it can be used where a `B` is expected due the **Liskov** principle.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez 1. No, they can be used for implicit conversions. 2. "you are not directly calling any method of the B class" But the expected type IS `B`, which can trigger the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImplicitClass` is equivalent to

```
class ImplicitClass(value: A) extends B

implicit def ImplicitClass(value: A): ImplicitClass
```

You can see the difference: this implicit conversion takes `value: A` as an *explicit* parameter, unlike your `def implicitConversion`. And if you change to

```
def foo()(implicit a: A) = bar()(a)
```

you'll see it work.